# ListView onItemLongClickListener is not working properly

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working on a `ListView` and I have used `setBackgroundColor` inside `onItemLongClickListener` on the selected item. My problem is that when I am doing this and scrolling, it is setting color of some invisible child of `ListView` too. How can it be solved.

Comment: Inside your listadapter, do you get your convertview from the tag? It might retain the backgroundcolor that you set there?

Comment: at scroolling time want color invisible ?

Comment: It's because listview re-uses its items when scrolling, to be smooth and process less. I think you should set background color to default color in your list adapter. So, any item has default color, until user long-clicks it and you set new background color just for that item.

Comment: @ankitmakwana I was just checking that which item is long clicked , so I set its color by calling setOnItemClickListener and by getting the view of item. It is working but it is setting some of other item color too which are invisible at that time. I know it on scrolling and it is in a pattern.

Comment: @aneal it is simple and I have used 2nd argument view of onItemLongClick to set color. It is working but setting some invisible item colors too.

Comment: @ePeace I was simply changing the color of item which is long clicked. I only used once  and it changed its color too but on scrolling i am seeing some other items also  changed there color too  but I have not clicked them.

Comment: Try setting your default background color in the getView method of your adapter just to make sure it's set correct everytime.

Comment: @ePeace a piece of code will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is caused since a listview uses old views in order to avoid re-creation of views when you scroll.

in fact , this is common to all of the adapterView classes .

in order to handle this , store the status of the position of the view (using an arrayList or whatever collection you wish) and on the getView , if the position is set in the list to be of this background , use this background , otherwise use the default background.

for more information about listview , either read the API , or (and i highly recommend it) watch the video "[the world of listView](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" .

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the following attributes in your xml:

`

```
<ListView       
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:scrollingCache="false" >
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(...);
    }
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(defaultcolor);
    ...
}
```

This however will overwrite the background you set in the onlongclicklistener when that view would be redrawn. So you might want to keep a list of the positions of the clicked items so you can set these in the getView method.